# Why am I unable to access attribute of model in my view in ruby rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access a boolean attribute of a model in my view in an if statement but am getting an error. I have used the dot notation to access the attribute and it has wroked for me for another class.

This is my model

```
class ChatroomUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my controller

```
class ChatroomUsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
    @chatroom_user = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    redirect_to @chatroom
  end 

  def show
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
    @chatroom_user = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    @chatroom_user.update_attribute(:admin, true)
    redirect_to @chatroom
  end 

  def destroy
    @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
    @chatroom_user = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all
    redirect_to chatrooms_path
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def chatroom_user_params
    params.require(:chatroom_user).permit(:admin)
  end

end
```

This is my view

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <h5>Requests</h5>
  <ul>
    <% @chatroom.requests.each do |x| %>
      <li>
        <% @conversationrequest = User.find(x.user_id) %>
        <div class="post-image">
         <%= image_tag @conversationrequest.profile.avatar.url(:medium) %>
        </div>&nbsp;
        <%= link_to @conversationrequest.profile.first_name,user_path(x.user_id) %> has requested to join the conversation
      </li>
        <% @temporarychatroomuser = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id) %>
        <% if @temporarychatroomuser.admin %>
          <% temporarystring = 'Accept'+@conversationrequest.profile.first_name%>
          <%= link_to temporarystring, user_path(x.user_id) %>
        <%end%> 
      </li>
    <%end%>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

This is my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :models
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'pages#home'
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
  resources :users do
    resource :profile

  end

  resources :chatrooms do
    resources :requests
    resource :chatroom_users
    resources :messages
  end

  get '/search' => 'pages#search', :as => 'search_page'
end
```

This is my migration

```
class CreateChatroomUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :chatroom_users do |t|
      t.references :chatroom, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :admin, :default => false
      t.boolean :acceptedmember, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The error I get is undefined method `admin` for chatroom user

Comment: You're going to want to post a whole stacktrace and `ChatroomUser` class, but just guessing that you don't have an `admin` method/attribute on the class. Have you run migrations?

Comment: It looks to me like you might be missing an opening `<li>` tag.

Comment: There are a few issues...but the  `@chatroom_user = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create` should probably have a block where you sets some attributes....and this probably doesn't belong in the show action (or maybe it does, depending on your app logic).

Comment: It's a good practice to avoid to put logic in your view. Basically your `@conversationrequest`   and `@temporarychatroomuser` variable shouldn't be set in your view. Moreover instead using `@temporarychatroomuser` I guess you could just call `@chatroom_user` from you show action contoller (sound to be the same request). Speculating your are in show view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `where`, which returns a relation, not a single entity.

Instead of `where` use `find_by` to return a single entity (or `nil` if none is found)

---

FWIW:

This is trivially easy to diagnose by either `pry`ing at that point in the template (which is the wrong place to do this much work) and inspecting the variable.

The REPL (`rails console`) is also a quick and easy way to understand what's being returned from various queries.

Comment: <% @temporarychatroomuser = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).first %> worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to write

```
  has_many :chatroom_users
```

in your app/models/chatroom.rb